# assertion error in junit test in java

Tags: java, junit

guys i have this service

```
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDao departmentDao;
    //... other functions 

    @Override
    public Department getDepartment(int depid) {
        return departmentDao.getDepartment(depid);
    }
}
```

and my test unit is

```
Department department = new Department();

@Autowired
private DepartmentDao myDao;

@Autowired
private DepartmentService service;


@Test
public void testGetDepartment(){
    department.setDepId(111);
    department.setDepName("merna");
    assertEquals(department, service.getDepartment(111));
}
```

but it gives me

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<com.dineshonjava.model.Department@f9b5552> but was:<com.dineshonjava.model.Department@4d4960c8>
```

any help  ??

Comment: Does your `Department` class override `equals()` ?

Comment: It isn't because they have the same ID that the objects are equals. Override equals and don't forget to override hashcode too respecting both contracts.

Answer (score 3):

You should override the equals method in your Department class:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
      if(object == null) {
          return false;
      } 
      if(this == object) {
          return true;
      }
      Department otherDepartment = (Department) object;
      if(this.getDepId() == otherDepartment.getDepId()) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to assert two different java object which are logically same, One which you created and other is returned by the service.

As told in comments by someone that you need to override your equal method and provide the logic as on what basis those two object are equal. in you case I guess two different Department object are equal if they have same depId. This logic should be there in equals method of Department.java for assertEqual to work.

Alternatively if you don't want to do that, you can check for particular primitive value rather than the whole object comparison.

```
@Test
public void testGetDepartment(){
 department.setDepId(111);
 department.setDepName("merna");
 assertEquals(department.getDepName(), service.getDepartment(111).getDepName());
}
```

But this is assuming that value you are putting in test case is same as it's being returned by DB (or from wherever).